# Is it possible to skip certain files from being commited in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am using SVN in my Ruby on Rails project. I have changed a number of files.

I usually commit my changes using:

```
svn commit -m "test_commit"
```

Its possible to commit individual files using:

```
svn ci -m "test_commit" file1 file2 dir/file3
```

But in this case I have almost 40 files to be commited. So adding all the file locations is a tedious task.

So I want to skip a couple of files and then commit it. Is it possible in SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *change list* in Subversion. Change lists are a way of grouping files for a common action. Commands such as `svn commit`, `svn revert`, `svn status`, and the various properties commands can all operate on a change list.

To create a changelist, use the `svn changelist` or `svn cl` command:

```
$ svn changelist <change_List_Name> <file> [<file2....>]
```

If there are too many files, you can use the `--targets` parameter to specify a file that contains the list of files you want to put in a change list:

```
$ svn changelist --targets <file_name>
```

For example, you could create your changelist file with `

> file.txt`then edit that`file.txt` to contain only the files you want to commit.

Then, use:

```
$ svn commit --changelist <change_list_name>
```

to commit just the files you want. Or,

```
$ svn commit --cl --keep-changelists
```

To keep that changelist of files in case you do more work on them.

Of course, you could forget changelists and just try the `--targets` parameter of the `svn commit` command. This is suppose to allow you to list files you want to commit in another file (much like how the `--targets` parameter works with `svn changelist`). I haven't tried that particular one, so I can't say how that works.

---

### Addendum

> Could you please explain 'svn changelist --targets ' with another example?

Imagine I have a working copy, and I've run `svn st` on it:

```
$ svn st
? foo.txt
M bar/bar.txt
D foofoo/foo.out
A barfu/barbar.sh
```

I am fixing Bug #103. This includes the changes to `foofoo/foo.out` and `bar/bar.txt`, but not to `barfu/barbar.sh` which was another bug I was working on.

If I run the the following:

```
$ svn status | awk '/^[MDA]/ {print $2}'
bar/bar.txt
foofoo/foo.out
barfu/barbar.sh
```

Notice that it gives me the files that were modified, deleted, and added, in my working copy, but not files in the working directory that aren't in the repo or files in the repo, but not in the working copy. This also doesn't give me a status of the files -- just the file names. I want to create a changelist for Bug #103, so I'll create a file called `bug103.txt`, and then edit it to remove the files that shouldn't be there:

```
$ svn status | awk '/^[MDA]/ {print $2}' > bug103.txt
```

Using my favorite text editor, I removed all the files that don't belong to Bug #103 from my `bug103.txt:

```
$ cat bug103.txt
bar/bar.txt
foofoo/foo.out
```

Now I have all of the files that deal with Bug #103 in my changelist in a file called `bug103.txt`, I'll create the change list for Bug #103:

```
$ svn cl --targets bug103.txt BUG103
```

Now, I can use the changelist to manipulate the status of my files. Let's check in this changelist:

```
$ svn --cl BUG103 -m"Fixed BUG #103"
```

This checked in the two files involved in Bug #103, but not `barfu/barbar.sh`.

Comment: Could you please explain 'svn changelist --targets <file_name>' with another example?

Comment: When using 'svn status | awk `/^[MDA]/ {print $2}`' I get the following error: -bash: /^[MDA]/: No such file or directory
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...

Comment: You need quotes around the awk program. That is `awk '/^[MDA]/ {print $2}'` Note the quote before the first forward slash and after the closing curly brace. This prevents the shell trying to interpolate the `awk` program. Usually, you use single quotes, so the shell leaves the awk field variables like `$2` alone.

Answer (score 0):

If the files you don't want to update are under the same directory, you can enter the first directory that doesn't contains them, and push the svn from there:

```
svn commit -m "comment"
```

try `svn status` before so you will be sure what you are pushing.

Comment: This is only working when the files are not in the same folder

Comment: No. the files are under different directories.